# Android FileProvider's getUriforFile(context, authority, file), what's context should i use?

Tags: android, file

where is context from?
it is my code

```
        String pathName = Save_Path + "/" + mSelectedItem.name + ".apk";
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        File file = new File(pathName);
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+"FileProvider" , file);

        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(intent);
```

and i need context but i don't know where is the context from.
My code is copied from my method in Framgent, and when i used to getContext, it got null.

Answer (score 0):

It only needs an Activity, Service or Application.
If you want to use it anywhere, you can define a static variable in your Application to store its own instance.